# what is the Wilcoxon-Mantel-Haenszel?

Tags: cochran-mantel-haenszel

I want to know that difference of between Wilcoxon-Mantel-Haenszel and Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel method in Shift analysis.

Comment: Maybe I'm being ignorant here but never heard anything like Wilcoxon-Mantel-Haenszel. Are you perhaps referring to Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney?

Comment: On page 1313 of this paper(Treatment effects for which shift or binary analyses are advantageous in acute stroke trials, Jeffrey L. Saver, Neurology, 2009;72:1310-1315.), WMH is mentioned in the Table 3 description. So, I searched for this, but I didn`t know it.

Comment: Looks more like a mistake than an actual test... there's no explanation about Wilcoxon-Mantel-Haenszel test in the paper but only about Wilcoxon's rank sum test, also referred to as Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test. Hope this helps